# SBT / Good way to override a plugin's setting

Tags: scala, sbt, aspectj

I want to change the aspectj version used by [this plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-aspectj/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/SbtAspectj.scala) (line 59).
Indeed, I want to use aspectj version **1.8.0** and not 1.7.3.
I sent a message to the creator but I'm stuck until he could answer since I've got a Spring-Data component that depends on 1.8.0.

The current plugin's setting is:

```
lazy val aspectjSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = inConfig(Aspectj)(defaultAspectjSettings) ++ aspectjDependencySettings

  def defaultAspectjSettings = Seq(
    aspectjVersion := "1.7.3",
  .......
```

Mu current SBT for my own project starts as following:

```
val webApp = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
    .settings(aspectjSettings: _*)
```

What is a good way to "override" `aspectjVersion := "1.7.3"` by `aspectjVersion := "1.8.0"`?

I tried this, but doesn't seem to work.

```
.settings(Seq(aspectjVersion := "1.8.0") ++ aspectjSettings.filterNot(_.key.key.label == "aspectjVersion"): _*)
```

I still have this error:

```
warning bad version number found in /Developpements/play-2.2.3/repository/cache/org.aspectj/aspectjrt/jars/aspectjrt-1.8.0.jar expected 1.7.3 found 1.8.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at line 56 the settings are defined with

```
 inConfig(Aspectj)(defaultAspectjSettings) ...
```

which means that each key will be defined for the AspectJ config, so I *think* you need to override them in that config rather than without any config:

```
.settings(aspectjVersion in Aspectj := "1.8.0")
```

Comment: Indeed :) However, I still get the issue: `warning bad version number found in /Developpements/play-2.2.3/repository/cache/org.aspectj/aspectjrt/jars/aspectjrt-1.8.0.jar expected 1.7.3 found 1.8.0` :(   May you have any idea? Only this plugin needs 1.7.3 by default. It's as if the version override happens AFTER the process of the plugin's instruction.

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't seem to work regarding the plugin code. So here's a gist representing all my SBT configuration dealing with this plugin: https://gist.github.com/mica16/d16b891882a439fd38c5 and a solution I tried but in vain..  (I specified the three 1.8.0 dependencies at the top of my SBT and tried to avoid the plugin to reference 1.7.3)

Comment: In a file `ivy-0.9.4.xml` (of the plugin) there is `"<dependency org="org.aspectj" name="aspectjtools" rev=« 1.7.3 » conf="compile->default(compile)"/>` I tried to change manually 1.7.3 to 1.8.0 but still the issue of version conflict occurs.

Comment: I succeeded by adding this line:  `dependencyOverrides += "org.aspectj" % "aspectjtools" % "1.8.0"`